# cant overide configure method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

i am using spring security in my spring boot project i want i cant overide configure method

```
  @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurer {

@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
}
}
```

i tried many it time but i cant overide the configure method

Answer (score 1):

you are extending the class with "webSecurityConfigurer" .Try to extend it with

"WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter"